# How to define a trait method to get a value that can be a type set by its implementors?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a question concerning the definition of a specific trait. Basically I want to define a trait which provides a function to get the id (or key) of a struct which could identify it.
However, I got stuck and don't know how to define the trait (or the concrete implementation).

For example I have this struct `Data` here:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data{
    id: String,
    value: i32
}
```

Now let's say I want to create a trait which only consists of a single function. This function should provide some kind of key (hence hashable, etc.):

```
trait Entity {
    fn get_id<K: Eq + PartialEq + Hash>(&self) -> K;
}
```

But I got stuck when I want to implement the trait. For example I get the error message **mismatched types** for the following snippet:

```
impl Entity for Data {
    fn get_id<String>(&self) -> String {
        self.id.clone()
    }
}
```

What can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Your last code snippet _shadows_ the type name `String` with a generic type parameter of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you wrote it implies that the caller decides what the type should be which seems isn't what you want. You should move the generic type to the trait definition.

```
trait Entity<K: Eq + PartialEq + Hash> {
    fn get_id(&self) -> K;
}
impl Entity<String> for Data {
    fn get_id(&self) -> String {
        self.id.clone()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code let's the *caller* of `get_id` decide which type the returned id should be. That's not what you want however. Now depending on if each struct can have different ids or only a single one there's 2 ways how an implementation can determine the type.
If each struct should only implement `Entity` once with a sinlge type then an associated type is the solution:

```rust
trait Entity {
    type Id: Eq + PartialEq + Hash;
    fn get_id(&self) -> Self::Id;
}

impl Entity for Data {
    type Id = String;
    fn get_id(&self) -> String {
        self.id.clone()
    }
}
```

If you want to enable multiple, different ids for the same struct, you can go with [Tobi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77123466/442760) and use a type parameter on the trait instead.